# mysql : unable to retrieve the desired data properly

Tags: mysql

Here's my db :
[image: link]

My aim is to retrieve all rows which contains all `admin_ngp` and only those `yes` which are next to `admin_ngp`.Something like this:
[image: link]

I feel like a simple intersection operation would be enough to get my result. However, I'm unable to get the desired result. here's my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM artist_list 
WHERE uploaded_by = 'admin_ngp' IN (SELECT * 
                                    FROM artist_list 
                                    WHERE changed_by_admin = 'yes')
```

Comment: What do you meam with "which are next to admin_ngp" ??

Comment: Your where cluase doesn't make any sense

Comment: @nacho something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFnNk.png

Comment: Do you also need the ones where the `name` and `bio` also have 'admin_ngp' but may or may not have 'yes' in `changed_by_admin`?

Comment: @DeadLock Nope. Uploaded_By and changed_By_admin are required.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an OR in your where:

```
SELECT * 
FROM artist_list 
WHERE (uploaded_by = 'admin_ngp' AND name='admin_ngp' AND bio='admin_ngp') 
      OR (changed_by_admin = 'yes' AND uploaded_by = 'admin_ngp')
```

Comment: Nope. If I use OR operation, then the result would fetch something like this. The rows of admin_mum isn't desired.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/47xIJ.png

Comment: Just try now, you didn't let me finish

Answer (score 0):

Don't over-think it. I guess this is all you need.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM artist_list 
    WHERE 
        uploaded_by = 'admin_ngp' and changed_by_admin = 'yes'
;
```

Comment: Running your query, would result in skipping of the marked rows, which isn't desirable.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCNhZ.png

Comment: Um... in that case it seems like you don't really care whether the value of `changed_by_admin` is yes or not. Is that correct?

Comment: Do you just need the result of `SELECT * 
    FROM artist_list 
    WHERE 
        uploaded_by = 'admin_ngp'`; ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Case 1**
if you want uploaded_by is 'admin_ngp' then changed_by_admin should be 'yes' or name and bio should be 'admin_ngp'

```
SELECT * 
FROM artist_list 
WHERE Case when uploaded_by = 'admin_ngp' and changed_by_admin = 'yes'then 1 when name = 'admin_ngp' and bio = 'admin_ngp' then 1 else 0 end = 1
```

**Case 2**
if you want uploaded_by is 'admin_ngp' then changed_by_admin should be 'yes' or either name or bio should be 'admin_ngp'

```
SELECT * 
FROM artist_list 
WHERE Case when uploaded_by = 'admin_ngp' and changed_by_admin = 'yes'then 1 when name = 'admin_ngp' then 1 when bio = 'admin_ngp' then 1 else 0 end = 1
```